# Access variable in function from another function. php

Tags: php, function, return

I have this function

---

```
function theme_status_time_link($status, $is_link = true) {
    $time = strtotime($status->created_at);
    if ($time > 0) {
        if (twitter_date('dmy') == twitter_date('dmy', $time) && !setting_fetch('timestamp')) {
            $out = format_interval(time() - $time, 1). ' ago';
        } else {
            $out = twitter_date('H:i', $time);
        }
    } else {
        $out = $status->created_at;
    }
    if ($is_link)
        $out = "<a href='status/{$status->id}' class='time'>$out</a>";
    return $out;
}
```

### and this

```
function twitter_is_reply($status) {
    $html = " <b><a href='user/{$status->from->screen_name}'>{$status->from->screen_name}</a></b><br /> $actions $link<br />{$text} <small>$source</small>";
}
```

I need to pass the variable $out from the first function to the second function, precisely to the $html variable in the second function. However, everything I try either gives me errors and outputs nothing. Without using globals because it appears multiple times in my script. Thanks.

Comment: Why do not you use reference:
`theme_status_time_link($status, $is_link = true, &$buffer){ ... }`
`function twitter_is_reply($status, &$buffer) { .. }`
Is it what you think? By this you will be able to pass a reference to a variable. Tell me if this is your point.

The second thing is you can call the second function in the first function, immediately before return.

Comment: can't you extends twitter_is_reply with a second parameter function `twitter_is_reply($status, $out) {...}` ? If else - provide more info how twitter_is_reply should be called...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use functions send it as an argument:

```
function twitter_is_reply($status, $html) {
    $html .= " <b><a href='user/{$status->from->screen_name}'>{$status->from->screen_name}</a></b><br /> $actions $link<br />{$text} <small>$source</small>";

    return $html;
}
```

Usage:

```
$out = theme_status_time_link();

echo twitter_is_reply('helloworld', $out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you start to understand why OO is so good.
Create one class, make the $out a member of it and the two functions, make them methods of that class.

Comment: If I understood any of the above, I wouldn't be asking this question.